# bibitem symbol change in thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, baposter

Using `thebibliography` environment, I would like to change bibitem symbol. So instead of

```
[1] Jon Symbolmaster, The Art of Changing bibitem Symbols
```

there should be e.g.

```
* Jon Symbolmaster, The Art of Changing bibitem Symbols
```

or with `\blacktriangleright` symbol.

I know, it's easy when using `beamer` with `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[triangle]` command. But I use `baposter` and so I'm helpless.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[landscape, a0paper, fontscale=0.285]{baposter}

\definecolor{yellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.9,0.0}
\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0.0,1.0}

\definecolor{lightyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.3,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lightestyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.05,0.0}


\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=0.5em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=lighteryellow, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=lightestyellow, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=reddishyellow, % Border color
headerColorOne=yellow, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=reddishyellow, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=black, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=lightyellow, % Background color of the content boxes
boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.19\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rectangle, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=1.5pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
{}
{Bibitem Symbols}
{Jon Symbolmaster}
{}

 \headerbox{References}{name=references}{

     \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em}
       \begin{thebibliography}{99}

        \bibitem{jon}
        Jon Symbolmaster (2016),
        \newblock The Art of Changing bibitem Symbols       

       \end{thebibliography}
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE for us to fiddle with it?

Comment: @HATEthePLOT see EDIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to get `*`, you could add the following macro to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item[*]\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
   {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

or for getting `\blacktriangleright` please use the following after adding `amssymb` package:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item[$\blacktriangleright$]\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

So that the MWE will look like:

```
\documentclass[landscape, a0paper, fontscale=0.285]{baposter}

\definecolor{yellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.9,0.0}
\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0.0,1.0}

\definecolor{lightyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.3,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lightestyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.05,0.0}

\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item[*]\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=0.5em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=lighteryellow, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=lightestyellow, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=reddishyellow, % Border color
headerColorOne=yellow, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=reddishyellow, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=black, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=lightyellow, % Background color of the content boxes
boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.19\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rectangle, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=1.5pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
{}
{Bibitem Symbols}
{Jon Symbolmaster}
{}

 \headerbox{References}{name=references}{

     \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em}
     \def\theenumiv{*}
       \begin{thebibliography}{99}

        \bibitem{jon}
        Jon Symbolmaster (2016),
        \newblock The Art of Changing bibitem Symbols       

       \end{thebibliography}
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```